# How to catch an exception in phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am working on a functional test to check a specific user can't update a resource, in this case the API replays with a 404 error. This is the test:

```
static::createClient()->request(
        'PUT',
        '/api/bookings/' . $bookingIdToUpdate,
        [
            'auth_bearer' => $token,
            'json' => [
                'requestedBy' => 'a new value for this field',
            ],
        ]
    );
    self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, 'This user is not expected to be able to update this booking');
```

when I run this test, I get a 404 response, which is fine:

```
Testing App\Tests\Integration\BookingTest
2020-01-21T15:00:07+00:00 [error] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "Not Found" at /var/www/html/vendor/api-platform/core/src/EventListener/ReadListener.php line 116
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 38.89 seconds, Memory: 42.50 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

so the test is passing but the console is still displaying the exception. so I added this just before client call:

```
$this->expectException(NotFoundHttpException::class);
```

and this is the result:

```
Testing App\Tests\Integration\BookingTest
2020-01-21T15:15:05+00:00 [error] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "Not Found" at /var/www/html/vendor/api-platform/core/src/EventListener/ReadListener.php line 116
F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 41.39 seconds, Memory: 42.50 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\Integration\BookingTest::testUserCantUpdateABookingFromAnotherOrganisation
Failed asserting that exception of type "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException" is thrown.

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

as you can see the exception is thrown, but at the same time I am getting an error saying it was not. Any idea how to catch this?

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing to the correct class in your test? Try to reference Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException::class instead in your expectException

Comment: yes I am sure I am referencing the correct class.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you call the following method first:

```
$client->catchExceptions(false);
```

For example:

```
public function testUserCantUpdateABookingFromAnotherOrganisation()
{
    $this->expectException(NotFoundHttpException::class);

    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->catchExceptions(false);

    $client->request('GET', '/foo/bar');

    $client->request(
        'PUT',
        '/api/bookings/' . $bookingIdToUpdate,
        [
            'auth_bearer' => $token,
            'json' => [
                'requestedBy' => 'a new value for this field',
            ],
        ]
    );

    self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, 'This user is not expected to be able to update this booking');
}
```